# TextView, autolink and no scrolling

Tags: android, textview, autolink

I have a `TextView` that can't fit it's content (I'm animating the height). Now that I've added autolinking, the view can be scrolled whenever it's height is smaller that it should be. How do I disable this? `description.setMovementMethod(null);` blocks link clicking and `description.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());` scrolls.

Edit:
I haven't found how fix this, though I've found a workaround.

```
if(descriptionCropped){
    descriptionCropped = false;
    //enable movement on expanded view
    description.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
}else{
    descriptionCropped = true;
    //disable movement on cropped view, have to reset onClick for some reason
    //workaround for scrolling text when the view is smaller than it's content
    description.setMovementMethod(null);
    description.setOnClickListener(this);
}
```

Where `this` is an `OnClickListener`.